# postgis update geom from lat and long

Tags: postgis

I have a table that contains a lat/long column... i'd like to have a trigger that populate the geom column when a row gets inserted into the database. are there examples that I can look at?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Do you not know how to build a trigger? or not know how to make a geometry (presumably point) from latitude and longitude? or do you have something that "should work" but doesn't do the update the way you expect? Please update the question (click edit below the question to enable this) to tell us more about your problem, what you've already tried, what happened, and what you expected to happen instead. Thanks!

Comment: Please check out http://ceg-sense.ncl.ac.uk/geoanorak/cloudsensedbschema.html and http://twiav-tt.blogspot.ae/2012/07/postgis-using-latitude-and-longitude-to.html might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Why not insert them using ST_MAKEPPOINT(long lat, 4326) at first place ? , Other solutions are: Create UPDATE or INSERT  TRIGGER  which does ST_MAKEPOINT , CREATE VIEW which has ST_MAKEPOINT(lon,lat, 4326) as geom column  and use that